# Can I fetch multiple Connect accounts with 1 call with the Stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments

From the [Stripe Docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve?lang=dotnet)
I'm aware I can fetch 1 Connected account (.Get()) and I'm aware I can fetch all Connected accounts (.List(options)) from my platform account.

**QUESTION** - I'm looking to see if there's a way to fetch multiple accounts by passing in an array of ids?

ex. I want to fetch the accounts of ids 1, 5, 9

I don't see anything from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible, no. You'd need to make a single API call to retrieve each Account object.

Comment: ok thanks. That sucks. I have customers that might have multiple Connect accounts and when I load a page for them to show them their accounts (bank account info) I'll have to make multiple calls to Stripe. :(